# How to: Dynamically allowed IP address list for port forward filter

Tags: networking, vpn, firewall, port-forwarding, authentication

I have been using OpenVPN to be remotely connected to my home network from my Android device. Using tasker the OpenVPN connection is automatically established when I leave my home Wi-Fi. The problem is that the OpenVPN client is unreliable and at times takes too long to connect.

I am looking at using port forwarding again since it is faster and more reliable, but knowing of the security risks I want to add IP based filtering on the incoming connections to the open ports. The only problem is that the IP's on mobile networks are not fixed.

Is there a way to "authenticate" the newly assigned mobile device IP on my home firewall. The idea is to have a white list of allowed IP addresses that are dynamically updated after authentication. The mobile device would authenticate through an open port on the firewall with the new dynamically assigned IP from the mobile provider. This IP is then added to the white list of the firewall. I am using a Mikrotik router as firewall.

his should ideally all happen automatically in the background on the Android device. Is there an existing communication/authentication standard that does the same thing? Has anyone thought of such an solution? Any other suggestions?

Comment: So *any* phone could authenticate itself, and then you'd allow it on?

Comment: The solution _is_ openvpn, or a vpn solution of some sort.

Comment: I am thinking of using ssl authentication via https with some tasker script that runs on ip change on the mobile device. I have tried OpenVPN as stated in the post.